# Возникает фатальная ошибка при попытке получить access_token через API VK PHP SDK

Tags: php, sdk

Собственно, делаю всё по документации. Через composer установил на PHPStorm, версия 7.2, использую OpenServer.

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Andrew
 * Date: 24.04.2018
 * Time: 21:20
 */

require 'vendor\autoload.php';

$app = [
    'app_id' => id_приложения,
    'secure_key' => "защищенный ключ приложения",
    'service_key' => 'сервисный ключ доступа'
];
/*
$vk = new VK\Client\VKApiClient();
$oauth = new VK\OAuth\VKOAuth();
$client_id = $app['app_id'];
$redirect_uri = 'localhost';
$display = VK\OAuth\VKOAuthDisplay::PAGE;
$scope = array(VK\OAuth\Scopes\VKOAuthUserScope::WALL, VK\OAuth\Scopes\VKOAuthUserScope::GROUPS);
$state = $app["secure_key"];

$browser_url = $oauth->getAuthorizeUrl(VK\OAuth\VKOAuthResponseType::CODE, $client_id, $redirect_uri, $display, $scope, $state);
*/


$oauth = new VK\OAuth\VKOAuth();
$client_id = $app['app_id'];
$client_secret = $app['secure_key'];
$redirect_uri = 'localhost';
$code = 'bukvi_i_cifri';
// взял отсюда после выполнения закомментированного кода выше из адресной строки: http://localhost:63342/vk_bot/bot.php?_ijt=bukvi_i_cifri

$response = $oauth->getAccessToken($client_id, $client_secret, $redirect_uri, $code);

$access_token = $response['access_token'];
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

> Fatal error: Uncaught VK\Exceptions\VKClientException: Invalid http status: 401 in C:\Users\Andrew\PhpstormProjects\vk_bot\vendor\vkcom\vk-php-sdk\src\VK\OAuth\VKOAuth.php:180 Stack trace: #0 C:\Users\Andrew\PhpstormProjects\vk_bot\vendor\vkcom\vk-php-sdk\src\VK\OAuth\VKOAuth.php(144): VK\OAuth\VKOAuth->checkHttpStatus(Object(VK\TransportClient\TransportClientResponse)) #1 C:\Users\Andrew\PhpstormProjects\vk_bot\vendor\vkcom\vk-php-sdk\src\VK\OAuth\VKOAuth.php(130): VK\OAuth\VKOAuth->checkOAuthResponse(Object(VK\TransportClient\TransportClientResponse)) #2 C:\Users\Andrew\PhpstormProjects\vk_bot\bot.php(36): VK\OAuth\VKOAuth->getAccessToken(id_app, 'secure_key', 'localhost', 'code') #3 {main} thrown in C:\Users\Andrew\PhpstormProjects\vk_bot\vendor\vkcom\vk-php-sdk\src\VK\OAuth\VKOAuth.php on line 180

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: отредактировал.

Comment: Вы версию указали?

Comment: Её же не требуется указывать, если нужна актуальная версия

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переменная `$redirect_uri` в коде и значение поля `Website address` (Адрес сайта) в [настройках приложения](https://vk.com/apps?act=manage) должны совпадать.

Comment: Благодарю за информацию.

Answer (score 1):

API недавно обновилось, теперь версия (v) - обязательный параметр.

Comment: К сожалению, даже указание версии не помогло

    $vk = new VK\Client\VKApiClient(('5.74'));